# Read volatile variable has persistent effect? Misra C

Tags: c, volatile, misra

Reading the Misra C guideline, I bumped into the following example:

```
extern volatile int v1, v2;
int t;

t = v1 + v2;
```

Per Misra C reading the variables v1 and v2 has a *persistent side effect*. I was wondering, why is that? Why reading a volatile variable may affect the execution state at that point? **Note:** Not assigning the sum to variable t, but just the reading itself.

Definition of *persistent side effect*: "A side effect is said to be persistent at a particular point in execution if it *might have an effect on the execution state at that point*." [Reference: Misra C, Appendix J]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MISRA-C as such, but the C language itself. The definition is found in the C standard (C11 5.1.2.3):

> Accessing  a  volatile  object,  modifying  an  object,  modifying  a  file,  or  calling  a  function that does any of those operations are all *side effects*, which are changes in the state of the execution  environment.

It is somewhat common to have hardware peripheral flag registers that change their value upon read. For example: reading a status register followed by reading a data register is a common way to clear flags in UART or SPI hardware.

For this reason, MISRA-C wants you to isolate volatile accesses into simple expressions, so that you don't get unexpected results such as in `x && my_volatile`, where `my_volatile` may or may not be evaluated and updated. The correct approach is to isolate the volatile access to a line of its own:

```
if(x) 
{ 
  int tmp = my_volatile;
  // do stuff with tmp
}
```

These rules also prevents you from writing dysfunctional code such as:

```
REGISTER |= FLAG1;
REGISTER |= FLAG2;
...
```

resulting in multiple writes to the register which causes execution overhead and possibly unwanted side effects. The above bad code scenario is sadly far more common in embedded firmware than you'd expect. Again, it is easiest to store the results in a temporary variable and isolate the write to a single line:

```
uint32_t reg = FLAG1 | FLAG2 | ...;
REGISTER = reg;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Misra-C standard (Misra-C:2004), section 6.

> The volatile type qualifier is provided in C to denote objects whose
> value can change independently of the execution of the program (for
> example an input register). If an object of volatile qualified type is
> accessed this may change its value. C compilers will not optimise out
> reads of a volatile. In addition, as far as a C program is concerned,
> a read of a volatile has a side-effect (changing the value of the
> volatile).

This argues that a volatile that represents an input register may change its value when read, so reading a volatile is considered a side-effect.

Comment: @Alex Just think about a FIFO of a UART: If you read the buffer register, the oldest entry is returned, and the FIFO read pointer is advanced.

Comment: @thebusybee you're right, nice example! Thank you :)

Comment: @PaulHankin I've accepted your answer, but please add either the example above or any other example to make it complete!

Comment: The meaning should be intended as that you always access the storage locations, even if you rewrite the same value. Any side effect related to this access will be repeated each time, persistently, for each `volatile` access.